# in php ! how to extract a variable value of a response (json) and echo it

Tags: php

i get a response of my code . that response has a variable value which is before a constant string and after another constant string . i want get this variable and echo it .

example : i have this json:

```
{ "id": "tok_1Cs0osBsNOaFjmrSIBFEAkPd", "object": "token", "client": 
{ "id": "card_1Cs0osBsNOaFjmrSl9fAs5hT", "object": "name", "address_city": null, "address_country": null, "address_line1": null, "address_line1_check": null, "address_line2": null, "address_state": null, "address_zip": "74455", "address_zip_check": "unchecked", "country": "RU",  "metadata": {}, "name": "2022 Nemelek\r\n", "tokenization_method": null }, "client_ip": "41.199.157.183", "created": 1532578278, "livemode": true, "type": "Uid", "used": false }
```

i wanna extract tok_1Cs0osBsNOaFjmrSIBFEAkPd which is after { "id": " and before ", "object":

btw : this value is variable but what is before and first word after it are constants

how can i code it in php

Comment: kindly add your effort to do the same, e.g. code etc . You should not expect people to write a code for you from scratch, that is not how SO works

Comment: You use Google. You type in "php json", and use the php.net result: http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php. This page also lists the available functions of PHP for handling JSON, such as [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Next time, search and read first.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode()`:

```
$str = '{ "id": "tok_1Cs0osBsNOaFjmrSIBFEAkPd", "object": "token", "client": { "id": "card_1Cs0osBsNOaFjmrSl9fAs5hT", "object": "name", "address_city": null, "address_country": null, "address_line1": null, "address_line1_check": null, "address_line2": null, "address_state": null, "address_zip": "74455", "address_zip_check": "unchecked", "country": "RU", "metadata": {}, "name": "2022 Nemelek\r\n", "tokenization_method": null }, "client_ip": "41.199.157.183", "created": 1532578278, "livemode": true, "type": "Uid", "used": false }';

$v = json_decode($str);

//tok_1Cs0osBsNOaFjmrSIBFEAkPd
echo $v->id;
```